# Are they correct and colloquial?

Tags: grammar, colloquialisms

I'm really curious about it.

Which one is correct ?  Also, are they colloquial English ?

**1.My grandmother already passed away, but she lived to comb gray hair.**

**2.My grandmother already passed away, but she made old bones.**

**3.My grandmother already passed away, but she lived long.**

**4.My grandmother already passed away, but she had lived long.**

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Neither *lived to comb grey hair* nor *made old bones* is an established phrase. The first one is fairly clear, but the second I would find confusing (you do not normally speak of people *making* their bones: she *grew old bones* would be a little more understandable, but still might be confusing).

The third and fourth ones are all right, but as Tim says *lived long* is not colloquial. The difference between them is that the fourth one places her living long in the past relative to when she passed away - since this is necessarily the case, it is probably a more natural way to say it. But the third one is also possible: it moves the focus to her living, rather than keeping the focus point on her passing away.

I haven't said anything about the first half. In my (British) dialect, I would not use *already* with the simple past (like Tim); but my understanding is that for some (mainly American) speakers it is possible. ("... already passed away" occurs 9 times in the COCA - the Corpus of Contemporary American English - most are "have/has/had already passed away", but one is "she already passed away"

Comment: Americans do use the simple past with *already*, but the particular combination in the OP's sentence sounds odd to me.

Comment: Then, Would you please tell me the most natural way to say it ?

Comment: It's hard to answer that without knowing more about the context in which you want to say it, but I would probably say something like "My grandmother is no longer with us, but she lived to an old age", or perhaps "to a fine old age" if I want to be enthusiastic. Others would no doubt say "passed away", but I hate that particular euphemism. And depending on who I was talking to, I might say "is dead" rather than any euphemism.

Answer (score 0):

None are correct:

1. My grandmother *has* already passed away, but she lived to comb gray hair.
2. My grandmother *has* already passed away, but she made old bones.
3. My grandmother *has* already passed away, but she lived *for a long time*.
4. My grandmother *has* already passed away, but she lived long.

The *already* is not needed in any of them.